# Unable to view partitions created

Tags: sql, database, oracle, sqlplus, partitioning

I am able to create the table with the partitions

```
create table Employee (
PRIMARY KEY (dateofbirth, surname, firstname),
dateofbirth date,
surname varchar(20),
firstname varchar(20) not null
)
Partition by hash(dateofbirth)(
partition C1,
partition C2,
partition C3,
partition C4
);
```

When I run this

```
select * from user_tab_partitions where table_name ='Employee';
```

I get nothing (no rows selected)? How do I see the partitions I created?

I was looking for something like this as the output

```
PARTITION_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TQ84_LIST_PARTITION_EAST
TQ84_LIST_PARTITION_NORTH
TQ84_LIST_PARTITION_SOUTH
TQ84_LIST_PARTITION_WEST
```

(Ignore the table name, and column names, they might not be appropriate as the original table is long, the problem stands however.)

Comment: that's not what you really ran...if it was, it wouldn't have executed. you can't have column names like date or number - they are reserved words.

Comment: Hi, Yes i made the changes, however, the problem is still standing

Comment: @Annon did you converted 'Employee' to upper case ? => 'EMPLOYEE'

Comment: Yes, I just get a lot of random results like this : http://prntscr.com/sg2l6o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

all oracle metadata is in upper case:

select * from user_tab_partitions where table_name ='TIME';

Comment: or even easier, no quotes at all

Answer (score 1):

You have your table named `'time'`, but you query for table `'timeslot'`

Comment: Yep, my bad. made the edit, I just altered the table for you guys so its easier to understand.. but the problem still stands.